# onDestinationChanged is not called when launching a single top destination again

Tags: android, androidx, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have a destination that is intended to be used as single top. defined as :

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondaryPage"
        android:name="SecondaryPageFragment"
        android:label="SecondaryPage" >
    <argument
            android:name="pageId"
            app:argType="integer" />
</fragment>
<action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_secondaryPage"
        app:destination="@id/secondaryPage"
        app:launchSingleTop="true" />
```

i need the pageId argument in the parentActivity, so i'm getting it on `onDestinationChanged` function.

whenever i navigate to a `SecondaryPageFragment`, for first time the `onDestinationChanged` function is called, then when the `SecondaryPageFragment` is the current destination (its on top), navigating again to `SecondaryPageFragment` with different arguments doesnt cause a `onDestinationChanged` call.  but if i navigate to lets say FragmentA, then navigating to `SecondaryPageFragment` causes a `onDestinationChanged` function call.

if i change the `launchSingleTop` option to false, the bug is fixed and `onDestinationChanged` is called. but i dont want to stack the `SecondaryPageFragment`.

im using androidx's NavigationComponent.

```
fun initNavController(){
       //...init nav controler
       navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(this)
}
override fun onDestinationChanged(
    controller: NavController,
    destination: NavDestination,
    arguments: Bundle?
) {
    Timber.d("arguments on destination changed ${arguments?.getInt("pageId")} $arguments")
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "navigating again to another SecondaryPageFragment"? when your current destination is `SecondaryPageFragment ` (in the top) you try to navigate to `SecondaryPageFragment ` again ?

Comment: yes, you got it right. sorry for my bad english